# What is the purpose of global keyword in javascript comments

Tags: javascript, global

I have noticed that some javascript files have comments at the top like this:

```
/* global Blob */
/* global MediaRecorder */
/* global MediaSource */
/* global URL */
```

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/#inline-configuration) and similar linters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are used for linters (like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/)).

Denoting them as a `global` tells the linter not to complain when it finds it later on in the file. It tells it that it's defined elsewhere.